# ¿cómo retornar un arreglo de bytes de un web api?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

tengo la siguiente api:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetExpediente()
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        var expediente = db.Expediente.Select(e => new ExpedientePOCO
        {
            idExpediente = e.idExpediente,
            NombreExpediente = e.NombreExpediente,
            CantidadDocumento = e.CantidadDocumento,
            DuenioExpediente = e.DuenioExpediente,
            FechaCreacion = e.FechaCreacion,
            Documentos = e.Documento.Select(x => new DocumentoPOCO
            {
                NombreDocumento = x.NombreDocumento,
                idExpediente = x.idExpediente,
                FechaCreacion = x.FechaCreacion,
                idDocumento = x.idDocumento,
                Archivos = x.Archivo.Select(a=>new ArchivoPOCO
                    { idDocumento = a.idDocumento,
                        idArchivo = a.idDocumento,
                        NombreImagen = a.NombreImagen,
                        ArchivoImg = a.ArchivoImg})
            })
        });
        if (expediente.Any())
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, expediente);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
                "No se encontraron expedientes.");
        }
    }
```

dónde ArchivoImg es un arreglo de bytes, sin embargo cuando trato de cargarlos (en formato json) me dice que no ajustó el espació para traer el arreglo de bytes, algúna idea de cómo podría reparar esto? Soy nuevo en esto de las web api's.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: La recomendacion es que la api responsa la info (pero no la imagen), la imagen la podrias realizar en otra peticion (a una api que devuelve solo la imagen). Pero bueno es lo que generalmente se realiza, pero no se exactamente tu requerimiento.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que la mejor opción seria pasar ese `byte[]` a base 64 i devolver la string, y luego hacer el proceso contrario.

```
Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

Puede ser que el json devuelto sea muy grande, así que quizás seria mejor, definir otro endpoint en la api para devolver solo el fichero, y en el json para cada fichero devolver la url donde se puede descargar.

Si no me equivoco ademas hay algun parametro de configuracion que limita el tamaño de json. 
[Busqueda rápida en google sobre esto](http://rion.io/2013/04/28/handling-larger-json-string-values-in-net-and-avoiding-exceptions/)

Comment: +1 en "...Puede ser que el json devuelto sea muy grande, así que quizás seria mejor, definir otro endpoint en la api para devolver solo el fichero, y en el json para cada fichero devolver la url donde se puede descargar."